# SVG logo animation to fill and disappear at the end

Tags: svg

I need to animate this logo to fill smoothly and disappear on the end of animation, for example like on this website: https://largo.studio/ I'm trying all of the combination of css, but nothing works.

```css
.path {
       stroke-dasharray: 1300;
       stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
       animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
     }

     @keyframes dash {
       0% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 822;
         fill: white;
      }
       50% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 600;
      }
      70% {
         fill: #db0d83;
         stroke-dashoffset: 400;
      }
      100% {
         fill: white;
      }
    }
```

```html
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1824 485" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:22.926;"><path class="path" fill="white" stroke="#db0d83" stroke-width="4" d="M327.236,354.205c0,46.271 -17.896,80.534 -53.581,102.797c-24.88,15.278 -67.548,22.917 -128.113,22.917l-143.064,0l0,-470.769l128.659,0c57.946,0 98.431,6.764 121.567,20.297c33.501,19.643 50.306,51.726 50.306,96.25c0,51.944 -26.736,87.736 -80.316,107.379c69.731,13.531 104.542,53.907 104.542,121.129m-45.833,-229.818c0,-36.229 -12.221,-61.548 -36.774,-75.953c-22.263,-13.093 -59.692,-19.642 -112.182,-19.642l-108.362,0l0,197.738l109.671,0c98.432,0 147.647,-34.049 147.647,-102.143m22.917,225.89c0,-37.976 -13.095,-65.258 -39.286,-81.844c-26.189,-16.587 -67.439,-24.881 -123.749,-24.881l-117.2,0l0,216.725l116.546,0c51.508,0 86.864,-3.929 106.071,-11.786c38.412,-15.715 57.618,-48.452 57.618,-98.214m377.139,-46.611c0,55.437 -13.422,98.976 -40.267,130.623c-26.845,31.647 -63.402,47.47 -109.672,47.47c-45.832,0 -82.175,-15.825 -109.017,-47.47c-26.842,-31.642 -40.267,-75.186 -40.267,-130.623c0,-55.435 13.422,-98.978 40.267,-130.625c26.845,-31.645 63.185,-47.469 109.017,-47.469c46.27,0 82.831,15.829 109.672,47.469c26.841,31.645 40.267,75.19 40.267,130.625m-21.607,0c0,-49.762 -11.571,-88.832 -34.811,-117.2c-23.241,-28.369 -54.454,-42.561 -93.521,-42.561c-39.067,0 -70.172,14.192 -93.194,42.561c-23.021,28.368 -34.483,67.438 -34.483,117.2c0,49.761 11.458,88.829 34.483,117.203c23.025,28.371 54.127,42.557 93.194,42.557c39.067,0 70.278,-14.186 93.521,-42.557c23.243,-28.374 34.811,-67.442 34.811,-117.203m345.71,168.928l-20.298,0l0,-53.037c-21.387,41.468 -59.581,62.202 -114.581,62.202c-77.697,0 -116.547,-40.595 -116.547,-121.783l0,-227.2l20.297,0l0,220.215c0,37.86 7.453,65.566 22.263,82.935c14.865,17.434 39.285,26.191 73.332,26.191c38.412,0 67.747,-11.277 87.737,-33.938c11.869,-13.452 19.718,-29.89 23.572,-49.107c2.687,-13.404 3.927,-34.373 3.927,-62.637l0,-183.659l20.298,0l0,339.818Zm356.842,-109.346c-3.928,36.668 -17.9,65.589 -41.904,86.757c-24.004,21.165 -54.782,31.754 -92.321,31.754c-44.522,0 -80.316,-15.933 -107.379,-47.796c-27.062,-31.864 -40.595,-75.298 -40.595,-130.297c0,-55.435 13.536,-98.98 40.595,-130.625c27.059,-31.64 63.511,-47.469 109.344,-47.469c35.793,0 65.042,9.389 87.738,28.154c22.694,18.769 36.447,44.96 41.249,78.571l-20.953,0c-4.365,-27.062 -16.372,-48.564 -36.011,-64.492c-19.64,-15.93 -43.651,-23.9 -72.023,-23.9c-39.285,0 -70.496,14.187 -93.631,42.561c-23.133,28.371 -34.701,67.438 -34.701,117.2c0,49.761 11.57,88.831 34.701,117.203c23.131,28.368 54.346,42.557 93.631,42.557c29.682,0 54.894,-9.171 75.624,-27.5c20.731,-18.328 33.066,-42.559 36.993,-72.678l19.643,0Zm96.249,109.346l-20.298,0l0,-470.116l20.298,0l0,470.116Zm273.687,-470.116l-59.582,87.738l-20.953,0l50.416,-87.738l30.119,0Zm88.392,302.498l-265.831,0l0,5.237c0,46.263 11.567,83.373 34.594,111.308c23.025,27.938 52.489,41.905 88.501,41.905c28.155,0 52.601,-8.079 73.442,-24.227c20.839,-16.145 35.247,-38.192 43.105,-66.129l20.297,0c-7.42,33.174 -23.597,59.561 -48.562,79.227c-24.898,19.61 -54.235,29.462 -87.955,29.462c-44.195,0 -79.305,-15.854 -105.306,-47.47c-26.045,-31.67 -39.067,-75.186 -39.067,-130.623c0,-55.435 12.99,-98.98 38.958,-130.625c25.969,-31.64 61.001,-47.469 105.088,-47.469c44.087,0 78.902,14.627 104.433,43.869c25.533,29.243 38.303,70.285 38.303,123.094l0,12.441Zm-21.606,-19.642c0,-43.433 -10.917,-77.921 -32.629,-103.343c-21.712,-25.423 -49.87,-38.086 -84.573,-38.086c-36.011,0 -65.37,12.553 -88.173,37.758c-22.804,25.205 -35.576,59.802 -38.194,103.671l243.569,0Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path><path d="M327.236,354.205c0,46.271 -17.896,80.534 -53.581,102.797c-24.88,15.278 -67.548,22.917 -128.113,22.917l-143.064,0l0,-470.769l128.659,0c57.946,0 98.431,6.764 121.567,20.297c33.501,19.643 50.306,51.726 50.306,96.25c0,51.944 -26.736,87.736 -80.316,107.379c69.731,13.531 104.542,53.907 104.542,121.129Zm-45.833,-229.818c0,-36.229 -12.221,-61.548 -36.774,-75.953c-22.263,-13.093 -59.692,-19.642 -112.182,-19.642l-108.362,0l0,197.738l109.671,0c98.432,0 147.647,-34.049 147.647,-102.143Zm22.917,225.89c0,-37.976 -13.095,-65.258 -39.286,-81.844c-26.189,-16.587 -67.439,-24.881 -123.749,-24.881l-117.2,0l0,216.725l116.546,0c51.508,0 86.864,-3.929 106.071,-11.786c38.412,-15.715 57.618,-48.452 57.618,-98.214Zm377.139,-46.611c0,55.437 -13.422,98.976 -40.267,130.623c-26.845,31.647 -63.402,47.47 -109.672,47.47c-45.832,0 -82.175,-15.825 -109.017,-47.47c-26.842,-31.642 -40.267,-75.186 -40.267,-130.623c0,-55.435 13.422,-98.978 40.267,-130.625c26.845,-31.645 63.185,-47.469 109.017,-47.469c46.27,0 82.831,15.829 109.672,47.469c26.841,31.645 40.267,75.19 40.267,130.625Zm-21.607,0c0,-49.762 -11.571,-88.832 -34.811,-117.2c-23.241,-28.369 -54.454,-42.561 -93.521,-42.561c-39.067,0 -70.172,14.192 -93.194,42.561c-23.021,28.368 -34.483,67.438 -34.483,117.2c0,49.761 11.458,88.829 34.483,117.203c23.025,28.371 54.127,42.557 93.194,42.557c39.067,0 70.278,-14.186 93.521,-42.557c23.243,-28.374 34.811,-67.442 34.811,-117.203Zm345.71,168.928l-20.298,0l0,-53.037c-21.387,41.468 -59.581,62.202 -114.581,62.202c-77.697,0 -116.547,-40.595 -116.547,-121.783l0,-227.2l20.297,0l0,220.215c0,37.86 7.453,65.566 22.263,82.935c14.865,17.434 39.285,26.191 73.332,26.191c38.412,0 67.747,-11.277 87.737,-33.938c11.869,-13.452 19.718,-29.89 23.572,-49.107c2.687,-13.404 3.927,-34.373 3.927,-62.637l0,-183.659l20.298,0l0,339.818Zm356.842,-109.346c-3.928,36.668 -17.9,65.589 -41.904,86.757c-24.004,21.165 -54.782,31.754 -92.321,31.754c-44.522,0 -80.316,-15.933 -107.379,-47.796c-27.062,-31.864 -40.595,-75.298 -40.595,-130.297c0,-55.435 13.536,-98.98 40.595,-130.625c27.059,-31.64 63.511,-47.469 109.344,-47.469c35.793,0 65.042,9.389 87.738,28.154c22.694,18.769 36.447,44.96 41.249,78.571l-20.953,0c-4.365,-27.062 -16.372,-48.564 -36.011,-64.492c-19.64,-15.93 -43.651,-23.9 -72.023,-23.9c-39.285,0 -70.496,14.187 -93.631,42.561c-23.133,28.371 -34.701,67.438 -34.701,117.2c0,49.761 11.57,88.831 34.701,117.203c23.131,28.368 54.346,42.557 93.631,42.557c29.682,0 54.894,-9.171 75.624,-27.5c20.731,-18.328 33.066,-42.559 36.993,-72.678l19.643,0Zm96.249,109.346l-20.298,0l0,-470.116l20.298,0l0,470.116Zm273.687,-470.116l-59.582,87.738l-20.953,0l50.416,-87.738l30.119,0Zm88.392,302.498l-265.831,0l0,5.237c0,46.263 11.567,83.373 34.594,111.308c23.025,27.938 52.489,41.905 88.501,41.905c28.155,0 52.601,-8.079 73.442,-24.227c20.839,-16.145 35.247,-38.192 43.105,-66.129l20.297,0c-7.42,33.174 -23.597,59.561 -48.562,79.227c-24.898,19.61 -54.235,29.462 -87.955,29.462c-44.195,0 -79.305,-15.854 -105.306,-47.47c-26.045,-31.67 -39.067,-75.186 -39.067,-130.623c0,-55.435 12.99,-98.98 38.958,-130.625c25.969,-31.64 61.001,-47.469 105.088,-47.469c44.087,0 78.902,14.627 104.433,43.869c25.533,29.243 38.303,70.285 38.303,123.094l0,12.441Zm-21.606,-19.642c0,-43.433 -10.917,-77.921 -32.629,-103.343c-21.712,-25.423 -49.87,-38.086 -84.573,-38.086c-36.011,0 -65.37,12.553 -88.173,37.758c-22.804,25.205 -35.576,59.802 -38.194,103.671l243.569,0Z" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#e5097f;stroke-width:0.22px;"></path></svg>
```

Comment: The total length of the stroke is 12326 (calculated width getTotallength()) Use this number in the css for the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset

Comment: I created the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/naaatasha/j81kcuro/1/ the line does not animate using 12326 as in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the problem you have is that not everything disappears (or rather becomes white) when the animation ends. In that case, I would think that the problem is in the `stroke` declaration in the path

```css
.path {
       stroke-dasharray: 1300;
       stroke-dashoffset: 1500;
       animation: dash 4s linear forwards;
     }

     @keyframes dash {
       0% {
         stroke:#e5097f;
         stroke-dashoffset: 822;
         fill: white;
      }
       50% {
         stroke-dashoffset: 600;
      }
      70% {
         fill: #db0d83;
         stroke-dashoffset: 400;
      }
      100% {
         fill: white;
         stroke: white;
      }
    }
```

```html
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:serif="http://www.serif.com/" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1824 485" xml:space="preserve" style="fill-rule:evenodd;clip-rule:evenodd;stroke-miterlimit:22.926;"><path class="path" fill="white" stroke="#db0d83" stroke-width="4" d="M327.236,354.205c0,46.271 -17.896,80.534 -53.581,102.797c-24.88,15.278 -67.548,22.917 -128.113,22.917l-143.064,0l0,-470.769l128.659,0c57.946,0 98.431,6.764 121.567,20.297c33.501,19.643 50.306,51.726 50.306,96.25c0,51.944 -26.736,87.736 -80.316,107.379c69.731,13.531 104.542,53.907 104.542,121.129m-45.833,-229.818c0,-36.229 -12.221,-61.548 -36.774,-75.953c-22.263,-13.093 -59.692,-19.642 -112.182,-19.642l-108.362,0l0,197.738l109.671,0c98.432,0 147.647,-34.049 147.647,-102.143m22.917,225.89c0,-37.976 -13.095,-65.258 -39.286,-81.844c-26.189,-16.587 -67.439,-24.881 -123.749,-24.881l-117.2,0l0,216.725l116.546,0c51.508,0 86.864,-3.929 106.071,-11.786c38.412,-15.715 57.618,-48.452 57.618,-98.214m377.139,-46.611c0,55.437 -13.422,98.976 -40.267,130.623c-26.845,31.647 -63.402,47.47 -109.672,47.47c-45.832,0 -82.175,-15.825 -109.017,-47.47c-26.842,-31.642 -40.267,-75.186 -40.267,-130.623c0,-55.435 13.422,-98.978 40.267,-130.625c26.845,-31.645 63.185,-47.469 109.017,-47.469c46.27,0 82.831,15.829 109.672,47.469c26.841,31.645 40.267,75.19 40.267,130.625m-21.607,0c0,-49.762 -11.571,-88.832 -34.811,-117.2c-23.241,-28.369 -54.454,-42.561 -93.521,-42.561c-39.067,0 -70.172,14.192 -93.194,42.561c-23.021,28.368 -34.483,67.438 -34.483,117.2c0,49.761 11.458,88.829 34.483,117.203c23.025,28.371 54.127,42.557 93.194,42.557c39.067,0 70.278,-14.186 93.521,-42.557c23.243,-28.374 34.811,-67.442 34.811,-117.203m345.71,168.928l-20.298,0l0,-53.037c-21.387,41.468 -59.581,62.202 -114.581,62.202c-77.697,0 -116.547,-40.595 -116.547,-121.783l0,-227.2l20.297,0l0,220.215c0,37.86 7.453,65.566 22.263,82.935c14.865,17.434 39.285,26.191 73.332,26.191c38.412,0 67.747,-11.277 87.737,-33.938c11.869,-13.452 19.718,-29.89 23.572,-49.107c2.687,-13.404 3.927,-34.373 3.927,-62.637l0,-183.659l20.298,0l0,339.818Zm356.842,-109.346c-3.928,36.668 -17.9,65.589 -41.904,86.757c-24.004,21.165 -54.782,31.754 -92.321,31.754c-44.522,0 -80.316,-15.933 -107.379,-47.796c-27.062,-31.864 -40.595,-75.298 -40.595,-130.297c0,-55.435 13.536,-98.98 40.595,-130.625c27.059,-31.64 63.511,-47.469 109.344,-47.469c35.793,0 65.042,9.389 87.738,28.154c22.694,18.769 36.447,44.96 41.249,78.571l-20.953,0c-4.365,-27.062 -16.372,-48.564 -36.011,-64.492c-19.64,-15.93 -43.651,-23.9 -72.023,-23.9c-39.285,0 -70.496,14.187 -93.631,42.561c-23.133,28.371 -34.701,67.438 -34.701,117.2c0,49.761 11.57,88.831 34.701,117.203c23.131,28.368 54.346,42.557 93.631,42.557c29.682,0 54.894,-9.171 75.624,-27.5c20.731,-18.328 33.066,-42.559 36.993,-72.678l19.643,0Zm96.249,109.346l-20.298,0l0,-470.116l20.298,0l0,470.116Zm273.687,-470.116l-59.582,87.738l-20.953,0l50.416,-87.738l30.119,0Zm88.392,302.498l-265.831,0l0,5.237c0,46.263 11.567,83.373 34.594,111.308c23.025,27.938 52.489,41.905 88.501,41.905c28.155,0 52.601,-8.079 73.442,-24.227c20.839,-16.145 35.247,-38.192 43.105,-66.129l20.297,0c-7.42,33.174 -23.597,59.561 -48.562,79.227c-24.898,19.61 -54.235,29.462 -87.955,29.462c-44.195,0 -79.305,-15.854 -105.306,-47.47c-26.045,-31.67 -39.067,-75.186 -39.067,-130.623c0,-55.435 12.99,-98.98 38.958,-130.625c25.969,-31.64 61.001,-47.469 105.088,-47.469c44.087,0 78.902,14.627 104.433,43.869c25.533,29.243 38.303,70.285 38.303,123.094l0,12.441Zm-21.606,-19.642c0,-43.433 -10.917,-77.921 -32.629,-103.343c-21.712,-25.423 -49.87,-38.086 -84.573,-38.086c-36.011,0 -65.37,12.553 -88.173,37.758c-22.804,25.205 -35.576,59.802 -38.194,103.671l243.569,0Z" style="fill-rule:nonzero;"></path><path d="M327.236,354.205c0,46.271 -17.896,80.534 -53.581,102.797c-24.88,15.278 -67.548,22.917 -128.113,22.917l-143.064,0l0,-470.769l128.659,0c57.946,0 98.431,6.764 121.567,20.297c33.501,19.643 50.306,51.726 50.306,96.25c0,51.944 -26.736,87.736 -80.316,107.379c69.731,13.531 104.542,53.907 104.542,121.129Zm-45.833,-229.818c0,-36.229 -12.221,-61.548 -36.774,-75.953c-22.263,-13.093 -59.692,-19.642 -112.182,-19.642l-108.362,0l0,197.738l109.671,0c98.432,0 147.647,-34.049 147.647,-102.143Zm22.917,225.89c0,-37.976 -13.095,-65.258 -39.286,-81.844c-26.189,-16.587 -67.439,-24.881 -123.749,-24.881l-117.2,0l0,216.725l116.546,0c51.508,0 86.864,-3.929 106.071,-11.786c38.412,-15.715 57.618,-48.452 57.618,-98.214Zm377.139,-46.611c0,55.437 -13.422,98.976 -40.267,130.623c-26.845,31.647 -63.402,47.47 -109.672,47.47c-45.832,0 -82.175,-15.825 -109.017,-47.47c-26.842,-31.642 -40.267,-75.186 -40.267,-130.623c0,-55.435 13.422,-98.978 40.267,-130.625c26.845,-31.645 63.185,-47.469 109.017,-47.469c46.27,0 82.831,15.829 109.672,47.469c26.841,31.645 40.267,75.19 40.267,130.625Zm-21.607,0c0,-49.762 -11.571,-88.832 -34.811,-117.2c-23.241,-28.369 -54.454,-42.561 -93.521,-42.561c-39.067,0 -70.172,14.192 -93.194,42.561c-23.021,28.368 -34.483,67.438 -34.483,117.2c0,49.761 11.458,88.829 34.483,117.203c23.025,28.371 54.127,42.557 93.194,42.557c39.067,0 70.278,-14.186 93.521,-42.557c23.243,-28.374 34.811,-67.442 34.811,-117.203Zm345.71,168.928l-20.298,0l0,-53.037c-21.387,41.468 -59.581,62.202 -114.581,62.202c-77.697,0 -116.547,-40.595 -116.547,-121.783l0,-227.2l20.297,0l0,220.215c0,37.86 7.453,65.566 22.263,82.935c14.865,17.434 39.285,26.191 73.332,26.191c38.412,0 67.747,-11.277 87.737,-33.938c11.869,-13.452 19.718,-29.89 23.572,-49.107c2.687,-13.404 3.927,-34.373 3.927,-62.637l0,-183.659l20.298,0l0,339.818Zm356.842,-109.346c-3.928,36.668 -17.9,65.589 -41.904,86.757c-24.004,21.165 -54.782,31.754 -92.321,31.754c-44.522,0 -80.316,-15.933 -107.379,-47.796c-27.062,-31.864 -40.595,-75.298 -40.595,-130.297c0,-55.435 13.536,-98.98 40.595,-130.625c27.059,-31.64 63.511,-47.469 109.344,-47.469c35.793,0 65.042,9.389 87.738,28.154c22.694,18.769 36.447,44.96 41.249,78.571l-20.953,0c-4.365,-27.062 -16.372,-48.564 -36.011,-64.492c-19.64,-15.93 -43.651,-23.9 -72.023,-23.9c-39.285,0 -70.496,14.187 -93.631,42.561c-23.133,28.371 -34.701,67.438 -34.701,117.2c0,49.761 11.57,88.831 34.701,117.203c23.131,28.368 54.346,42.557 93.631,42.557c29.682,0 54.894,-9.171 75.624,-27.5c20.731,-18.328 33.066,-42.559 36.993,-72.678l19.643,0Zm96.249,109.346l-20.298,0l0,-470.116l20.298,0l0,470.116Zm273.687,-470.116l-59.582,87.738l-20.953,0l50.416,-87.738l30.119,0Zm88.392,302.498l-265.831,0l0,5.237c0,46.263 11.567,83.373 34.594,111.308c23.025,27.938 52.489,41.905 88.501,41.905c28.155,0 52.601,-8.079 73.442,-24.227c20.839,-16.145 35.247,-38.192 43.105,-66.129l20.297,0c-7.42,33.174 -23.597,59.561 -48.562,79.227c-24.898,19.61 -54.235,29.462 -87.955,29.462c-44.195,0 -79.305,-15.854 -105.306,-47.47c-26.045,-31.67 -39.067,-75.186 -39.067,-130.623c0,-55.435 12.99,-98.98 38.958,-130.625c25.969,-31.64 61.001,-47.469 105.088,-47.469c44.087,0 78.902,14.627 104.433,43.869c25.533,29.243 38.303,70.285 38.303,123.094l0,12.441Zm-21.606,-19.642c0,-43.433 -10.917,-77.921 -32.629,-103.343c-21.712,-25.423 -49.87,-38.086 -84.573,-38.086c-36.011,0 -65.37,12.553 -88.173,37.758c-22.804,25.205 -35.576,59.802 -38.194,103.671l243.569,0Z" style="fill:none;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke-width:0.22px;"></path></svg>
```